# join 3 tables into 1 table with a different number of rows in each table

Tags: php, mysql

i have 3 tables

table1

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aa |
| 2 | bb |
| 3 | cc |

table2

| id_t2 | id | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 2 | 12 |
| 3 | 2 | 13 |
| 4 | 3 | 14 |
| 5 | 3 | 15 |
| 6 | 3 | 16 |

table3

| id_t3 | id | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 17 |
| 2 | 1 | 18 |
| 3 | 1 | 19 |
| 4 | 2 | 20 |
| 5 | 3 | 21 |
| 6 | 3 | 22 |
| 7 | 3 | 23 |

and I want to join those 3 tables into 1 table like this

| id | name | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | 11 | 17 |
| 1 | aa | 0 | 18 |
| 1 | aa | 0 | 19 |
| 2 | bb | 12 | 20 |
| 2 | bb | 13 | 0 |
| 3 | cc | 14 | 21 |
| 3 | cc | 15 | 22 |
| 3 | cc | 16 | 23 |

```
<table border="1">
        <tr><th hidden>id</th><th>name</th><th>val2</th><th>val3</th></tr>
        <?php
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', '00');
        ?>
        <?php
            $query1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT table1.*, table2.val2, table3.val3 FROM table1     INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.id=table1.id ORDER BY id asc");
        $arr = array();
        while ($row  = mysqli_fetch_object($query1)) {
            $arr[$row->name][] = $row;
        }
        ?>
    
        <?php foreach ($arr as $key => $val) : ?>
            <?php foreach ($val as $k => $v) : ?>
                <tr>
                         <td hidden><?php echo $v->id ?></td>
                        <?php if ($k == 0) : ?>
                           <td rowspan="<?php echo count($val) ?>"><?php echo $v->name ?></td>
                        <?php endif ?>     
                        <td><?php echo $v->val2 ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $v->val3 ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </table>
```

and the result like this (not expecting)

| id | name | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | 11 | 17 |
| 1 | aa | 11 | 18 |
| 1 | aa | 11 | 19 |
| 2 | bb | 12 | 20 |
| 2 | bb | 13 | 20 |
| 3 | cc | 14 | 21 |
| 3 | cc | 16 | 22 |
| 3 | cc | 14 | 22 |
| 3 | cc | 16 | 23 |
| 3 | cc | 15 | 21 |
| 3 | cc | 14 | 23 |
| 3 | cc | 15 | 22 |
| 3 | cc | 16 | 21 |
| 3 | cc | 15 | 23 |

Comment: In both cases, (1) what you want and (2) what you get, the `id` column makes little sense. I also don't understand the logic behind the creation of the table you want.

Comment: is there any specific reason that `val2=11` should be on the same row as `val3=17`, instead of the next row `val3=18`?

Comment: the reason I ask that, is there is nothing in your data that shows any type of relationship between `val2=11` and `val3=17` that doesn't also apply to `val2=11` and `val3=18`. So I wonder why you want to use a HTML table to present the data in exactly this way.

Comment: I use the id relationship for the 3 tables where table 1 has data in table 2 with a dynamic number of data rows and so does table 1 also have data in table 3 with a dynamic number of data rows. for example name a has 1 val2 = 11 and 3 val3 = 17, 18,19

Comment: `ORDER BY id` is ambiguous, you need to specify the table, e.g. `ORDER BY table1.id`

Comment: Where does `val2 = 0` and `val3 = 0` come from in your desired result? That doesn't appear anywhere in the input.

Comment: Unless you add more specific joining conditions, you get a full cross product between the rows with the same ID in tables 2 and 3.

Comment: that's the problem for me, I hope that the name a for val2 which only has 1 data (1 row) = 11 doesn't appear duplicate 2 numbers 11 below it as in the table which I don't expect, but the 2 numbers 11 duplicates become empty or be 0 for inline with val3 which has 3 data rows for name a

Answer (score 1):

There's no way that MySQL can understand the relationship of this data, and put it into separate rows, without you having to do some kind of overly complex subqueries or join conditions.

For instance there is nothing in the structure of your data that tells MySQL that `val3` should be 17, when `val2` is 11, and to then produce a subsequent row where `val3` should be 18, but to not link `val2` in the same way, and instead set it to 0.

One option might be to use [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) on your `val2` and `val3`. You might consider it acceptable to display these in a single row, with comma separated values. From a human readability point of view, this might also be preferable, because a new row in an HTML table implies a correlation between all columns, and that kind of explicit correlation (between val2 and val3) simply does not exist.

You could use PHP's [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to separate `$v->val2` and `$v->val3` by commas into arrays, and then loop over those, to suitably format the results within a single cell.

Alternatively, you could use explode() and some more complex PHP logic to create new rows, according to the format you desire.

Answer (score 0):

As @SimonMayer posted in his answer, this is most probably not achievable in SQL code.

It is solvable in PHP:

```
$table1 = [
  [ 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'aa' ],
  [ 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'bb' ],
  [ 'id' => 3, 'name' => 'cc' ],
];

$table2 = [
  [ 'id_t2' => 1, 'id' => 1, 'val2' => 11 ],
  [ 'id_t2' => 2, 'id' => 2, 'val2' => 12 ],
  [ 'id_t2' => 3, 'id' => 2, 'val2' => 13 ],
  [ 'id_t2' => 4, 'id' => 3, 'val2' => 14 ],
  [ 'id_t2' => 5, 'id' => 3, 'val2' => 15 ],
  [ 'id_t2' => 6, 'id' => 3, 'val2' => 16 ],
];

$table3 = [
  [ 'id_t3' => 1, 'id' => 1, 'val3' => 17 ],
  [ 'id_t3' => 2, 'id' => 1, 'val3' => 18 ],
  [ 'id_t3' => 3, 'id' => 1, 'val3' => 19 ],
  [ 'id_t3' => 4, 'id' => 2, 'val3' => 20 ],
  [ 'id_t3' => 5, 'id' => 3, 'val3' => 21 ],
  [ 'id_t3' => 6, 'id' => 3, 'val3' => 22 ],
  [ 'id_t3' => 7, 'id' => 3, 'val3' => 23 ],
];

$grouped2 = [];
foreach ($table2 as $item) {
  $grouped2[$item['id']][] = $item['val2'];
}

$grouped3 = [];
foreach ($table3 as $item) {
  $grouped3[$item['id']][] = $item['val3'];
}

$result = [];
foreach ($table1 as $item) {
  $vars2 = $grouped2[$item['id']];
  $vars3 = $grouped3[$item['id']];
  $count = max(count($vars2), count($vars3));
  $rows = [];
  for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $rows[] = [
      'id'   => $item['id'],
      'name' => $item['name'],
      'var2' => $vars2[$i] ?? 0,
      'var3' => $vars3[$i] ?? 0
    ];
  }
  $result[] = $rows;
}

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => aa
                    [var2] => 11
                    [var3] => 17
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => aa
                    [var2] => 0
                    [var3] => 18
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => aa
                    [var2] => 0
                    [var3] => 19
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => bb
                    [var2] => 12
                    [var3] => 20
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => bb
                    [var2] => 13
                    [var3] => 0
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => cc
                    [var2] => 14
                    [var3] => 21
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => cc
                    [var2] => 15
                    [var3] => 22
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => cc
                    [var2] => 16
                    [var3] => 23
                )

        )

)
```